# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name for searchable gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I got this error

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property
>   with the name

I have 0 idea on how to use this method. I'm trying to do a searchable gridview which i follow this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article223.aspx). But even before i try to test, i cant even pass this error.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblpoliceid" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("policeid").ToString()) %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

How do i solve it? 
Regards. 
P.S: I would appreciate if anyone could give me some reference on how to do searchable gridview via databind instead of databound/

Answer (score 0):

```
The DataSource You binding to gridview does not have field "policeid"
```